# SQL join tables to itself provide incomplete results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a set of tables to collect from which I am trying to find a count of distinct ip address (ip) between two different blacklist (typeId) - basically intersect a table to itself.  however my query  of joining the table to itself provides strange results.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE feedz_ip2 (fileId INTEGER NOT NULL, ip NUMERIC, utime INT, typeId INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE feedz_ip_types (typeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type STRING UNIQUE);
CREATE INDEX ip_id ON feedz_ip2(ip);
CREATE INDEX types_id ON feedz_ip2(typeId);
sqlite> select * from feedz_ip2 limit 4;
1|86176256|1347929568|2
1|247463936|1347929568|2
1|247476224|1347929568|2
1|247478272|1347929568|2
sqlite> select * from feedz_ip_types;

1 | malwaredomains
2 | spamhaus
3 | badipset
4 | abuse.ch
5 | malwarepatrol

sqlite> select a.typeId, b.typeId, count(a.ip) 
          from feedz_ip2 a 
    inner join feedz_ip2 b on a.typeId != b.typeId and a.ip=b.ip 
      ;

5 | 3 | 9265512
```

What I am looking for really should be intersection for all the different lists

```
1|3|200
1|5|900
2|3|300
```

If there is no intersection or common IP addresses those column combination will not list.

I dont know if the query is really confusing to the sqlite or I am confused..

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/aed94/1/0  are you sure you are showing the exact output you get from that query?

Comment: Can you post the content of the table that you are self-joining (i.e. `feedz_ip2`)? You only posted `feedz_IP_types` that seems to be irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry there was no group by statement in the first set of results..
I updated the query.. above
      sqlite> select a.typeId, b.typeId, count(a.ip) from feedz_ip2 a inner join feedz_ip2 b on a.typeId != b.typeId and a.ip=b.ip;
      5|3|9265512

Comment: Doesn't taking the group by clause away cause the query to crash?

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful, since you appear to want to do a select count(distinct a.ip).  http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=690

Comment: Taking the group cause away provides some results that are strange.  May be the distinct is needed. I can always run multiple queries like "select a.typeId, b.typeId, count(a.ip) from (select distinct typeid, ip from feedz_ip2 where typeId=1) a inner join (select distinct typeid, ip from feedz_ip2 where typeId=3) b on a.ip = b.ip;" produces results like below

1|3|2418

While this is possible it is very painful once my typeId grow to a large number.  I need to Permutation/Combination of all of them.  Hope you guys know a better solution.

Comment: SELECT count(distinct a.ip) does not really solve the problem, like in Bernie Zimmerman's blog

Comment: isn't the original query (with group by typeIds) giving exactly the results you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the solution :

```
select a.typeId, b.typeId, count(*) from feedz_ip2 a inner join feedz_ip2 b on a.typeId != b.typeId and a.ip=b.ip group by a.typeId,b.typeId;
+--------+--------+----------+
| typeId | typeId | count(*) |
+--------+--------+----------+
|      1 |      3 |   471718 | 
|      1 |      4 |  3662405 | 
|      1 |      5 |   323609 | 
|      2 |      3 |      426 | 
|      3 |      1 |   471718 | 
|      3 |      2 |      426 | 
|      3 |      4 |   133002 | 
|      3 |      5 |    41596 | 
|      4 |      1 |  3662405 | 
|      4 |      3 |   133002 | 
|      5 |      1 |   323609 | 
|      5 |      3 |    41596 | 
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: you might want to use `<` instead of `!=` to get only one-sided results